# looking for rich text editor that integrates with react-final-form

Tags: richtext, react-final-form

I have not been able to find a rich text editor that works with react-final-form and have failed in my own attempts to integrate.

Comment: Did you make any progress since asking the question?

Comment: I don't remember. I ended up leaving the company I was looking into that for. Sorry.